# Can't send email from Nginx php - fpm based dedi?

Tags: nginx, php, dedicated-server

I have a site and it has contact page. in that page there is Email & Comment tab. Whenever someone Put his email & comment & click on submit mail should come to my email. but it is not working.

I am using this php file for mail function.

I have nginx & php - fpm installed in my dedicated server.

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "myemail@yahoo.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "contact.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

But mail is not coming to my email. it was working when i have apache. I am new to nginx. so how can i make it work for nginx.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See your php error logs and your MTA logs

Comment: It's likely that php-fpm runs under a different user than your apache did; also, you could have limited the code to its bare essentials first :)

Comment: There is nothing in my error logs.

Comment: post full code i mean where comes the `$_REQUEST` variables come from?

Answer (score 1):

There you go a very sweet alternative to using mail() function.

See last function for configuration.

```
<?php

  class Xmail{

    # LOG VAR
    public $log = Array();

    # NEW LINE
    private $line = "\r\n";

    # ATTACHED FILES
    public $files = Array();

    # CONFIG GENERAL
    private $tpl = "";
    private $mode = "mail";

    function setTPL($value) { if($value != "") $this->tpl = $value; }
    function setMODE($value) { if($value != "") $this->mode = $value; }

    # CONFIG SMTP
    private $smtp_host = "localhost";
    private $smtp_port = "25";
    private $smtp_username = "";
    private $smtp_password = "";

    function setSmtpHost($value) { if($value != "") $this->smtp_host = $value; }
    function setSmtpPort($value) { if($value != "") $this->smtp_port = $value; }
    function setSmtpUser($value) { if($value != "") $this->smtp_username = $value; }
    function setSmtpPass($value) { if($value != "") $this->smtp_password = $value; }

    # CONFIG SOCKET
    private $from = "sokmail@localhost"; // sender email address
    private $host = "localhost"; // your domain name here
    private $port = "25"; // it is always 25 but i think it's best to have this for tests when developper pc has port 25 blocked and server has alternate port [i use 26 cause 25 is locked for anti SPAM by ISP]
    private $time = "30"; // timeout [time short :D]
    private $test = false; // test mode, does not send the email but you can see the log up to the point of sending email, good to check email addresses if valid or server if black-listed

    function setFrom($value) { if($value != "") $this->from = $value; }
    function setHost($value) { if($value != "") $this->host = $value; }
    function setPort($value) { if($value != "") $this->port = $value; }
    function setTime($value) { if($value != "") $this->time = $value; }
    function setTest($value) { if($value != "") $this->test = $value; }

    # MAIN FUNCTION
    function mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachments = NULL) {

      # MESSAGE HTML
      $msg = str_replace("\'","'",$msg);
      $msg = str_replace('\"','"',$msg);

      # Use template if case
      if(is_file($this->tpl)){
        $html = implode("", file($this->tpl));
        $html = str_replace("{MESSAGE}", $msg, $html);
      }else
       $html = $msg;

      $boundary1 = '-----='.md5(uniqid(rand()));
      $boundary2 = '-----='.md5(uniqid(rand()));

      $message .= "\r\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
      $message .= "--".$boundary1."\r\n";
      $message .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n      boundary=\"$boundary2\"\r\n\r\n";

      # MESSAGE TEXT
      $message .= "--".$boundary2."\r\n";
      $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain;\r\n      charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
      $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
      $message .= strip_tags($msg) . "\r\n";
      $message .= "\r\n\r\n";

      # MESSAGE HTML
      $message .= "--".$boundary2."\r\n";
      $message .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n      charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
      $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";
      $message .= "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\r\n";
      $message .= "<html>\r\n";
      $message .= "<body>\r\n";
      $message .= str_replace("
", "<br/>", $html) . "<br/>\r\n";
      $message .= "</body>\r\n";
      $message .= "</html>\r\n\r\n";
      $message .= "--".$boundary2."--\r\n\r\n";

      if(is_array($attachments)) {
        foreach($attachments AS $file_url) {
          if(is_file($file_url)) {
            $file_name = pathinfo($file_url, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            $file_type = $this->find_mime(pathinfo($file_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            # ATTACHMENT
            $message .= "--".$boundary1."\r\n";
            $message .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type.";\r\n      name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
            $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n      filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n\r\n";

            $fp = fopen($file_url, 'r');
            do {
              $data = fread($fp, 8192);
              if (strlen($data) == 0) break;
              $content .= $data;
            }
            while (true);
            $content_encode = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            $message .= $content_encode."\r\n\r\n";
            $content = '';
            unset($content); 

          }
        }
      }
      $message .= "--".$boundary1."--\r\n\r\n";

      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n      boundary=\"$boundary1\"\r\n";

      if($this->mode == "smtp" || $this->mode == "mx")
       return $this->sokmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
      else {
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) return true;
        return false;
      }
    }

    # send mail directly to destination MX server
    function sokmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) {
      // get server based on mode
      if($this->mode == "mx") {
        list($user, $domain) = split("@",$to);
        getmxrr($domain, $mxhosts);
        $server = $mxhosts['0'];
      }else{
        $server = $this->smtp_host;
      }

      # open socket
      $socket = @fsockopen($server, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->time);
      if(empty($socket)) { return false; }
      if($this->parse_response($socket, 220, "SOCKET") != 220) { fclose($socket); return false; }

      # say HELO to our little friend
      fputs($socket, "EHLO " . $this->host . $this->line);
      if($this->parse_response($socket, 250, "HELO") != 250) { fclose($socket); return false; }

      # if SMTP
      if($this->mode == "smtp" && !empty($this->smtp_username) && !empty($this->smtp_password) ) {
        # start login
        fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN" . $this->line);
        if($this->parse_response($socket, 334, "AUTH LOGIN") != 334) { fclose($socket); return false; }

        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . $this->line);
        if($this->parse_response($socket, 334, "USERNAME") != 334) { fclose($socket); return false; }

        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . $this->line);
        if($this->parse_response($socket, 235, "PASSWORD") != 235) { fclose($socket); return false; }
      }

      # email from
      fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <" . $this->from . ">" . $this->line);
      if($this->parse_response($socket, 250, "MAIL FROM") != 250) { fclose($socket); return false; }

      # email to
      fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $to . ">" . $this->line);
      if($this->parse_response($socket, 250, "RCPT TO") != 250) { fclose($socket); return false; }

      # check for test mode
      if($this->test != true) {

        # send data start command
        fputs($socket, "DATA" . $this->line);
        if($this->parse_response($socket, 354, "DATA") != 354) { fclose($socket); return false; }

        # make the deposit :)
        fputs($socket, "Subject: " . $subject . $this->line);
        fputs($socket, "To: " . $to . $this->line);
        fputs($socket, $headers . $this->line);
        fputs($socket, $message . $this->line);
        fputs($socket, "." . $this->line); # this line sends a dot to mark the end of message
        if($this->parse_response($socket, 250, ".") != 250) { fclose($socket); return false; }
      }

      # say goodbye
      fputs($socket,"QUIT" . $this->line);
      $this->parse_response($socket, 221, "QUIT");
      fclose($socket);

      return true;
    }

    # parse server responces for above function
    function parse_response($socket, $expected, $cmd) {
      $response = '';
      $this->log[$cmd] = "";
      while (substr($response, 3, 1) != ' ') {
        if(!($response = fgets($socket, 256))) $this->log["ERROR RESPONSE"] = "Couldn't get mail server response codes.";
        else $this->log[$cmd] .= $response;
        # for security we break the loop after 10 cause this should not happen ever
        $i++;
        if($i == 10) return false;
      }

      # shows an error if expected code not received
      if(substr($response, 0, 3) != $expected) $this->log["ERROR CODES"] = "Ran into problems sending Mail. Received: " . substr($response, 0, 3) . ".. but expected: " . $expected;

      # access denied..quit
      if(substr($response, 0, 3) == 451) $this->log["ERROR QUIT"] = "Server declined access. Quitting.";

      return substr($response, 0, 3);
    }

    function find_mime($ext) {
      # create mimetypes array
      $mimetypes = $this->mime_array();

      # return mime type for extension
      if (isset($mimetypes[$ext])) {
        return $mimetypes[$ext];
      # if the extension wasn't found return octet-stream         
      } else {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
      }
    } 
    function mime_array() {
      return array(
        "ez" => "application/andrew-inset",
        "hqx" => "application/mac-binhex40",
        "cpt" => "application/mac-compactpro",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "bin" => "application/octet-stream",
        "dms" => "application/octet-stream",
        "lha" => "application/octet-stream",
        "lzh" => "application/octet-stream",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "class" => "application/octet-stream",
        "so" => "application/octet-stream",
        "dll" => "application/octet-stream",
        "oda" => "application/oda",
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "ai" => "application/postscript",
        "eps" => "application/postscript",
        "ps" => "application/postscript",
        "smi" => "application/smil",
        "smil" => "application/smil",
        "wbxml" => "application/vnd.wap.wbxml",
        "wmlc" => "application/vnd.wap.wmlc",
        "wmlsc" => "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc",
        "bcpio" => "application/x-bcpio",
        "vcd" => "application/x-cdlink",
        "pgn" => "application/x-chess-pgn",
        "cpio" => "application/x-cpio",
        "csh" => "application/x-csh",
        "dcr" => "application/x-director",
        "dir" => "application/x-director",
        "dxr" => "application/x-director",
        "dvi" => "application/x-dvi",
        "spl" => "application/x-futuresplash",
        "gtar" => "application/x-gtar",
        "hdf" => "application/x-hdf",
        "js" => "application/x-javascript",
        "skp" => "application/x-koan",
        "skd" => "application/x-koan",
        "skt" => "application/x-koan",
        "skm" => "application/x-koan",
        "latex" => "application/x-latex",
        "nc" => "application/x-netcdf",
        "cdf" => "application/x-netcdf",
        "sh" => "application/x-sh",
        "shar" => "application/x-shar",
        "swf" => "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "sit" => "application/x-stuffit",
        "sv4cpio" => "application/x-sv4cpio",
        "sv4crc" => "application/x-sv4crc",
        "tar" => "application/x-tar",
        "tcl" => "application/x-tcl",
        "tex" => "application/x-tex",
        "texinfo" => "application/x-texinfo",
        "texi" => "application/x-texinfo",
        "t" => "application/x-troff",
        "tr" => "application/x-troff",
        "roff" => "application/x-troff",
        "man" => "application/x-troff-man",
        "me" => "application/x-troff-me",
        "ms" => "application/x-troff-ms",
        "ustar" => "application/x-ustar",
        "src" => "application/x-wais-source",
        "xhtml" => "application/xhtml+xml",
        "xht" => "application/xhtml+xml",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "au" => "audio/basic",
        "snd" => "audio/basic",
        "mid" => "audio/midi",
        "midi" => "audio/midi",
        "kar" => "audio/midi",
        "mpga" => "audio/mpeg",
        "mp2" => "audio/mpeg",
        "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
        "aif" => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aiff" => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aifc" => "audio/x-aiff",
        "m3u" => "audio/x-mpegurl",
        "ram" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "rm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "rpm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
        "ra" => "audio/x-realaudio",
        "wav" => "audio/x-wav",
        "pdb" => "chemical/x-pdb",
        "xyz" => "chemical/x-xyz",
        "bmp" => "image/bmp",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "ief" => "image/ief",
        "jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
        "jpg" => "image/jpeg",
        "jpe" => "image/jpeg",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "tiff" => "image/tiff",
        "tif" => "image/tif",
        "djvu" => "image/vnd.djvu",
        "djv" => "image/vnd.djvu",
        "wbmp" => "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
        "ras" => "image/x-cmu-raster",
        "pnm" => "image/x-portable-anymap",
        "pbm" => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
        "pgm" => "image/x-portable-graymap",
        "ppm" => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
        "rgb" => "image/x-rgb",
        "xbm" => "image/x-xbitmap",
        "xpm" => "image/x-xpixmap",
        "xwd" => "image/x-windowdump",
        "igs" => "model/iges",
        "iges" => "model/iges",
        "msh" => "model/mesh",
        "mesh" => "model/mesh",
        "silo" => "model/mesh",
        "wrl" => "model/vrml",
        "vrml" => "model/vrml",
        "css" => "text/css",
        "html" => "text/html",
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "asc" => "text/plain",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "rtx" => "text/richtext",
        "rtf" => "text/rtf",
        "sgml" => "text/sgml",
        "sgm" => "text/sgml",
        "tsv" => "text/tab-seperated-values",
        "wml" => "text/vnd.wap.wml",
        "wmls" => "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript",
        "etx" => "text/x-setext",
        "xml" => "text/xml",
        "xsl" => "text/xml",
        "mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
        "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
        "mpe" => "video/mpeg",
        "qt" => "video/quicktime",
        "mov" => "video/quicktime",
        "mxu" => "video/vnd.mpegurl",
        "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        "movie" => "video/x-sgi-movie",
        "ice" => "x-conference-xcooltalk"
      );
    } 
  }

  # PHP does not have getmxr function on windows so I built one
  function win_getmxrr($hostname, &$mxhosts, &$mxweight=false) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) != 'WIN') return;
    if (!is_array ($mxhosts) ) $mxhosts = array();
    if (empty($hostname)) return;
    $exec='nslookup -type=MX '.escapeshellarg($hostname);
    @exec($exec, $output);
    if (empty($output)) return;
    $i=-1;
    foreach ($output as $line) {
      $i++;
      if (preg_match("/^$hostname\tMX preference = ([0-9]+), mail exchanger = (.+)$/i", $line, $parts)) {
        $mxweight[$i] = trim($parts[1]);
        $mxhosts[$i] = trim($parts[2]);
      }
      if (preg_match('/responsible mail addr = (.+)$/i', $line, $parts)) {
        $mxweight[$i] = $i;
        $mxhosts[$i] = trim($parts[1]);
      }
    }
    return ($i!=-1);
  }

  if (!function_exists('getmxrr')) {
    function getmxrr($hostname, &$mxhosts, &$mxweight=false) {
      return win_getmxrr($hostname, $mxhosts, $mxweight);
    }
  }

  function xmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers="", $attachments=""){
    $xmail = new Xmail();
    $xmail->setMODE("mx"); // default is mail; options: mail,smtp,mx

    // MX setup if in 'mx' mode
    $xmail->setFrom("someone@somedomain.com");
    $xmail->setHost($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    // SMTP SETUP if in 'smtp' mode
    $xmail->setSmtpHost("localhost");
    $xmail->setSmtpPort(25);
    $xmail->setSmtpUser("someuser");
    $xmail->setSmtpPass("somepassword");

    // from this point on you have to provide the same info as if you would use mail()
    if($headers == "")
     $headers = "From: <someone@somedomain.com>\r\n";

    // !!! DO NOT ADD MIME VERSION OR CONTENT TYPE HEADERS !!!

    // send the email
    $xmail->mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
  }

?>
```